# why when i plot a 3d figure inside a tkinter window it doesnt allow me to rotate the figure or zoom

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, tkinter

How can i interactively rotate or zoom the graph inside a tkinter figure?It generates a 3D plot but after that it remains static and I cannot interact with it and rotate/change the angle of the viewpoint.
If i plot it ouside the tk window it work fine, seems like the error its when triying to draw the figure inside the interface.

The funtion im triying to plot is the lorenz attractor from the matplotlib documentation

(python version 3.7.7)

If need more detail dont doub to ask me pls. thanks you

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk



#lorenz
def button_add():
   def lorenz(x, y, z, s=10, r=5, b=28):
       '''
       Given:
          x, y, z: a point of interest in three dimensional space
          s, r, b: parameters defining the lorenz attractor
       Returns:
          x_dot, y_dot, z_dot: values of the lorenz attractor's partial
              derivatives at the point x, y, z
       '''
       x_dot = s*(y - x)
       y_dot = r*x - y - x*z
       z_dot = x*y - b*z
       return x_dot, y_dot, z_dot

   dt = 0.01
   num_steps = 10000 

   # Need one more for the initial values
   xs = np.empty(num_steps + 1)
   ys = np.empty(num_steps + 1)
   zs = np.empty(num_steps + 1)

   # Set initial values
   xs[0], ys[0], zs[0] = (0., 1., 1.05)

   # Step through "time", calculating the partial derivatives at the current point
   # and using them to estimate the next point
   for i in range(num_steps):
       x_dot, y_dot, z_dot = lorenz(xs[i], ys[i], zs[i])
       xs[i + 1] = xs[i] + (x_dot * dt)
       ys[i + 1] = ys[i] + (y_dot * dt)
       zs[i + 1] = zs[i] + (z_dot * dt)

   # Plot
   fig = plt.figure()
   ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

   ax.plot(xs, ys, zs, lw=0.5)
   ax.set_xlabel("X Axis")
   ax.set_ylabel("Y Axis")
   ax.set_zlabel("Z Axis")
   ax.set_title("Lorenz Attractor")


   canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,w)
   
   canvas.draw()
   toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, w)
   toolbar.update()
   canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)   
##   plt.show()

#---------------interface---------------
w = Tk()
w.title("Lorenz")
w.geometry('800x600')
frame = tk.Frame(w)
frame.pack()

button1 = tk.Button(w, text='draw', fg='red', command= lambda : button_add())
button1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Deleting your previous question with my comment and posting the exact same question again has not changed anything - this is not reproducible because no window is generated. Maybe because the code is unchanged and [still not an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `matplotlib.figure.Figure` instead of `plt.figure` when embedding a `matplotlib` graph with `tkinter`. Also the sequence of `Figure`, `canvas` and `ax` creation matters:

```
def button_add():
    ...

    # Plot
    fig = Figure()

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, w)
    canvas.draw()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
    ax.plot(xs, ys, zs, lw=0.5)
    ax.set_xlabel("X Axis")
    ax.set_ylabel("Y Axis")
    ax.set_zlabel("Z Axis")
    ax.set_title("Lorenz Attractor")

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, w)
    toolbar.update()

    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

...
```

Comment: Specifically, `FigureCanvasTkAgg` must be called before `fig.add_subplot`, otherwise your plot will not be rotatable. (There may be other order requirements, but that's what I had backwards.)